ip address with lwip
I am trying to get a dynamic IP address with custom mpc5775b board and ksz8041 phy device in s32 design studio for pa but I don't get an IP address. I have used eth,phy,tcpip components. I have added my main.c file below.
#include "lwip/mem.h"
#include "lwip/pbuf.h"
#include "lwip/stats.h"
#include "lwip/snmp.h"
#include "lwip/ethip6.h"
#include "lwip/etharp.h"

#include "lwipcfg.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"

#include "enetif.h"
#include "enet_driver.h"

#include "osif.h"


#if defined(USING_OS_FREERTOS)
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#endif /* defined(USING_OS_FREERTOS) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "netifcfg.h"

#include "Cpu.h"
#include "clockMan1.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "ethernet1.h"
#include "device_registers.h"
#include<phy.h>

#include "lwip/prot/dhcp.h" // Include the header file where the enum is defined

#include "lwip/tcpip.h"
#include "lwip/netif.h"
#include "lwip/ip_addr.h"
#include "lwip/inet.h"
#include "lwip/tcp.h"
#include "lwip/udp.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include "lwip/sockets.h"
#include "lwip/opt.h"
#include "lwip/init.h"
#include "lwip/tcpip.h"
#include "lwip/dhcp.h"


#define LWIP_HDR_TCPIP_H

#include "lwip/opt.h"
#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/timeouts.h"
#include "lwip/netif.h"

    struct netif netif_ptr;
    struct netif netif_ptr_2;
    struct pbuf *p;

phy_id_t phy_id;
uint8_t phy = 0; // assuming you want to access PHY 0, change it as needed
phy_state_t phy_state;
int linkup;
phy_speed_t link_speed;
void link_up(uint8_t phy){

    status_t id_status = PHY_GetId(phy, &phy_id);
        if (id_status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
            printf("PHY ID: %lu\n", phy_id.oui);
        } else {
            printf("Failed to get PHY ID\n");
        }
      // Get state of the PHY device
        status_t state_status = PHY_GetState(phy, &phy_state);
           if (state_status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
               printf("PHY State: %d\n", phy_state);
           } else {
               printf("Failed to get PHY state\n");
           }
        // Get link status of the PHY device
           status_t link_status = PHY_GetLinkStatus(phy, &linkup);
              if (link_status == STATUS_SUCCESS && linkup) {
                  printf("Link is up\n");
              } else {
                  printf("Link is down\n");
              }

         // Get link speed of the PHY device
              status_t link_speed_status = PHY_GetLinkSpeed(phy, &link_speed);
                if (link_speed_status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    printf("Link speed: %d\n", link_speed);
                } else {
                    printf("Failed to get link speed\n");
                }

           phy_speed_t speed;
            PHY_GetLinkSpeed(phy, &speed);
            switch (speed)
            {
            case PHY_SPEED_10_MBPS:
                ENET_DRV_SetSpeed(INST_ETHERNET1, ENET_MII_SPEED_100M);

                break;
            case PHY_SPEED_100_MBPS:
                ENET_DRV_SetSpeed(INST_ETHERNET1, ENET_MII_SPEED_100M);

                break;
            //default:
            }
}
void link_down(uint8_t phy){}
void autoneg_failed(uint8_t phy){}
void autoneg_complete(uint8_t phy){}
void rx_callback(uint8_t instance, enet_event_t event, uint8_t ring){}

// Define the maximum number of network interfaces you expect
#define MAX_INTERFACES 2
static sys_sem_t tcpip_init_sem;

// Define structure to hold network information
typedef struct {
    char ip_address[16]; // Assuming IPv4 address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) with null terminator
    char net_mask[16];    // Assuming IPv4 netmask
    char gat_eway[16];    // Assuming IPv4 gateway
//    struct netif  netif_ptr; // Pointer to the network interface

} NetworkInfo;

// Global array to store network information
NetworkInfo network_info[MAX_INTERFACES];

// Function prototype for start_example_internal
void start_example_internal(void);

// Function prototype for lwip_init_complete_callback
void tcpip_init_complete_callback(void *arg);

volatile int exit_code = 0;
extern void start_example(void);

// TCP/IP initialization complete callback function
void tcpip_init_complete_callback(void *arg) {
    // Signal the semaphore to indicate TCP/IP initialization completion
    sys_sem_signal(&tcpip_init_sem);
}
void check_dhcp(void) {
//   struct dhcp my_dhcp_state;
    struct dhcp *dhcp_state = netif_dhcp_data(&netif_ptr);
                                  if (dhcp_state) {
                                      switch (dhcp_state->state) {
                                          case DHCP_STATE_BOUND:
                                              printf("DHCP bound\n");
                                              print_dhcp_state(dhcp_state);
                                              break;
                                          case DHCP_STATE_OFF:
                                              printf("DHCP off\n");
                                              break;
                                          default:
                                              printf("DHCP state: %u\n", dhcp_state->state);
                                              break;
                                      }
                                  } else {
                                      printf("DHCP not initialized\n");
                                  }
                              }

void start_example_internal(void) {

    int interface_count = 0; 
        ip_addr_t ipaddr, netmask, gw;

                                IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr,0,0, 0, 0);
                                IP4_ADDR(&netmask, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                                IP4_ADDR(&gw, 0, 0,0, 0);


                      if (linkup) {


                    struct netif *netif_result = netif_add(&netif_ptr, &addr, &netmask, &gw, NULL, enet_ethernetif_init, tcpip_input);
                          if (netif_result == NULL) {
                           printf("Failed to add network interface\n");
                          return 1; // Exit the program if netif_add fails
                          }
                          while(1)
                          {
                 netif_set_default(&netif_ptr);
//              netif_set_up(&netif_ptr);
                netif_set_link_up(&netif_ptr);

#if LWIP_DHCP
            err_t we=   dhcp_start(&netif_ptr);
            if (we==ERR_OK)
            {
                printf("dhcp  not failed");
            }
#endif

//            struct dhcp *my_dhcp_state;
//                           print_dhcp_state(&my_dhcp_state);


               netif_set_up(&netif_ptr);




       for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INTERFACES; i++) {

                  PHY_GetLinkStatus(phy, &linkup);
                  if (!linkup) {
                  printf("Link is down, waiting...\n");
                              }

                  strncpy(network_info[interface_count].ip_address, ip4addr_ntoa(&ipaddr), sizeof(network_info[interface_count].ip_address) - 1);
                  network_info[interface_count].ip_address[sizeof(network_info[interface_count].ip_address) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null termination

                  strncpy(network_info[interface_count].net_mask, ip4addr_ntoa(&netmask), sizeof(network_info[interface_count].net_mask) - 1);
                  network_info[interface_count].net_mask[sizeof(network_info[interface_count].net_mask) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null termination

                  strncpy(network_info[interface_count].gat_eway, ip4addr_ntoa(&gw), sizeof(network_info[interface_count].gat_eway) - 1);
                  network_info[interface_count].gat_eway[sizeof(network_info[interface_count].gat_eway) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null termination


                                  char ip[16];
                                  char ipgw[16];
                                  char ipnm[16];
                                  if (linkup) {
                                   strcpy(ip, ip4addr_ntoa(netif_ip4_addr(&netif_ptr)));
                                   strcpy(ipnm, ip4addr_ntoa(netif_ip4_netmask(&netif_ptr)));
                                   strcpy(ipgw, ip4addr_ntoa(netif_ip4_gw(&netif_ptr)));

                                  }
//               }
       }

}
                      }
}

int __read_console(void *buf, int len) {
    return 0;
}
int __write_console(const void *buf, int len) {
    return len;
}
int __close_console(int file) {
    return 0;
}


void print_dhcp_state(struct dhcp *dhcp_state) {
    printf("DHCP State:\n");
    printf("  Transaction ID (xid): %u\n", dhcp_state->xid);
    printf("  PCB Allocated: %u\n", dhcp_state->pcb_allocated);
    printf("  State: %u\n", dhcp_state->state);
    printf("  Tries: %u\n", dhcp_state->tries);
#if LWIP_DHCP_AUTOIP_COOP
    printf("  AutoIP Coop State: %u\n", dhcp_state->autoip_coop_state);
#endif
    printf("  Subnet Mask Given: %u\n", dhcp_state->subnet_mask_given);
    printf("  Request Timeout: %u\n", dhcp_state->request_timeout);
    printf("  T1 Timeout: %u\n", dhcp_state->t1_timeout);
    printf("  T2 Timeout: %u\n", dhcp_state->t2_timeout);
    printf("  T1 Renew Time: %u\n", dhcp_state->t1_renew_time);
    printf("  T2 Rebind Time: %u\n", dhcp_state->t2_rebind_time);
    printf("  Lease Used: %u\n", dhcp_state->lease_used);
    printf("  T0 Timeout: %u\n", dhcp_state->t0_timeout);
    printf("  Server IP Address: %s\n", ipaddr_ntoa(&dhcp_state->server_ip_addr));
    printf("  Offered IP Address: %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&dhcp_state->offered_ip_addr));
    printf("  Offered Subnet Mask: %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&dhcp_state->offered_sn_mask));
    printf("  Offered Gateway Address: %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&dhcp_state->offered_gw_addr));
    printf("  Offered T0 Lease: %u seconds\n", dhcp_state->offered_t0_lease);
    printf("  Offered T1 Renew: %u seconds\n", dhcp_state->offered_t1_renew);
    printf("  Offered T2 Rebind: %u seconds\n", dhcp_state->offered_t2_rebind);
#if LWIP_DHCP_BOOTP_FILE
    printf("  Offered SI Address: %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&dhcp_state->offered_si_addr));
    printf("  Boot File Name: %s\n", dhcp_state->boot_file_name);
#endif
}


int main(void)
{
  /*** Processor Expert internal initialization. DON'T REMOVE THIS CODE!!! ***/
  #ifdef PEX_RTOS_INIT
    PEX_RTOS_INIT();                   /* Initialization of the selected RTOS. Macro is defined by the RTOS component. */
  #endif
  /*** End of Processor Expert internal initialization.                    ***/
  /* Write your code here */

  /*** Don't write any code pass this line, or it will be deleted during code generation. ***/
  /*** RTOS startup code. Macro PEX_RTOS_START is defined by the RTOS component. DON'T MODIFY THIS CODE!!! ***/
  #ifdef PEX_RTOS_START
    PEX_RTOS_START();                  /* Startup of the selected RTOS. Macro is defined by the RTOS component. */
  #endif
  /*** End of RTOS startup code.  ***/

    status_t clock= CLOCK_DRV_Init(&clockMan1_InitConfig0);
   if( clock==STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
        printf("clock success");
            }


       CLOCK_SYS_UpdateConfiguration(0U, CLOCK_MANAGER_POLICY_AGREEMENT);

       status_t pin_init=  PINS_DRV_Init(NUM_OF_CONFIGURED_PINS, g_pin_mux_InitConfigArr);
      if (pin_init== STATUS_SUCCESS)
      {
           printf(" pins are initlilised");
      }
       SIU->FECCR = SIU_FECCR_FM_MASK;

       ENET_DRV_Init(INST_ETHERNET1, &ethernet1_State, &ethernet1_InitConfig0, ethernet1_buffConfigArr0, ethernet1_MacAddr);
       ENET_DRV_EnableMDIO(INST_ETHERNET1, false);

       //initialize phy framwwork and phy---
       status_t phy_frameinit= PHY_FrameworkInit(phyConfig, phyDrivers);
       if( phy_frameinit==STATUS_SUCCESS)
       {
           printf("phy_framinit complete");
       }
       status_t phuinit=PHY_Init(0U);
       if ( phuinit== STATUS_SUCCESS)
       {
           printf("phyinit success");
       }
       status_t link_speed_status = PHY_GetLinkSpeed(phy, &link_speed);
                    if (link_speed_status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                        printf("Link speed: %d\n", link_speed);
                    } else {
                        printf("Failed to get link speed\n");
                    }

       tcpip_init(NULL, NULL);


   void tcpip_init_complete_callback(void *arg);

//   while(1)
//   {
   status_t mainfuc = PHY_MainFunction(phy);
      if(mainfuc==STATUS_SUCCESS)
         link_up(phy);

         start_example_internal();
//   }

  /*** Processor Expert end of main routine. DON'T MODIFY THIS CODE!!! ***/
  for(;;) {
    if(exit_code != 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return exit_code;
  /*** Processor Expert end of main routine. DON'T WRITE CODE BELOW!!! ***/
} /*** End of main routine. DO NOT MODIFY THIS TEXT!!! ***/
/* END main */
/*!
** @}
*/
/*
** ###################################################################
**
**     This file was created by Processor Expert 10.1 [05.21]
**     for the NXP C55 series of microcontrollers.
**
** ###################################################################
*/


Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share the error message you're seeing, or the expected/actual results?
